# Will the main chat be unfrozen?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

Just curious if [the Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/17213/the-factory-floor) will be unfrozen, or if we've just given up on it ever being a thing again?

Comment: Feeds and system users with negative ID won't antifreeze room.

Answer (score 2):

'Tis done. I'm one of the room owners and probably should have been monitoring it more regularly -- that's my bad. The Factory Floor hasn't been active in a while, to put it mildly, stretching back to this spring. Hopefully it'll regain its old level of activity in the future, although the current issues the network's dealing with means prospects aren't ideal.

Comment: Only stretching back to spring? I've been popping in off and on hoping to run into someone for quite a bit longer, and it seems that it it stopped being active around the time some other certain events were taking place on the platform and some hostile people were allowed to run amok.

Comment: @AndyD273 Yeah, prior events were definitely the cause of the most significant dropoff, but I was talking about activity basically going to zilch. Might just have been my perception, though.